# Firefox not reading default configuration file

Tags: centos, configuration, firefox

I've built Firefox on CentOS and am having trouble setting default preferences. According to the [official docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Enterprise_deployment):

> 2. Create a JavaScript file in defaults/pref (on Linux) called autoconfig.js

Here is my `/tmp/ff-build/bin/defaults/pref/autoconfig.js`:

```
// First line must be a comment
pref("general.config.filename", "mozconfig.cfg");
pref("general.config.obscure_value", 0);
```

> 3. Create a .cfg file (by convention, mozilla.cfg — it can be any file
>      name really; it just has to match what is specified in
>      general.config.filename preference, above) in the program directory.

Here is my `/tmp/ff-build/bin/mozconfig.cfg` where the only firefox binary is:

```
// Disable updater
lockPref("app.update.enabled", false);
// make absolutely sure it is really off
lockPref("app.update.auto", false);
lockPref("app.update.mode", 0);
lockPref("app.update.service.enabled", false);

// Disable updater
lockPref("app.update.enabled¨, false);
```

Firefox will run fine without the `autoconfig.js` present, but with the configuration above Firefox fails to start with a popup displaying:

> Failed to read the configuration file. Please contact your system
>   administrator.

[image: Error message]

I've tried copying the `mozconfig.cfg` to several directories but with no change. How to make Firefox accept the `mozconfig.cfg` file? Am I misunderstanding the docs?

(Profiles are deleted and recreated so the solution won't involve adding anything to a ~/ based folder. The above is to get default preferences working. Thank you.)

Comment: You could try specifying an absolute filename as `general.config.filename`, just to see if it is reading the file. And surround the code with `try{ ...
  }catch(e){
    displayError("myerror", e);
  }`

Comment: I tried as you suggested to set an absolute path to `/tmp/ff-build/bin/mozconfig.cfg`, and I wrapped it in a try/catch block as suggested. The absolute path didn't work either, and try/catch didn't catch the error. The same generic alert comes up.

Comment: Perhaps there is some non-printing spurious character in the .cfg file. Try an empty file, then adding each line one by one till it breaks. `strace -e open` the binary program to see which files it is opening.

Comment: @meuh Found a strange `¨` that is supposed to be a `"`. Try/catch won't catch syntax errors, and there is no developer console. Was a tough one to spot. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The "Failed to read the configuration file. Please contact your system administrator." is a generic failure message. The problem could be in autoconfig.js or in mozconfig.js.

Running `strace -e ./firefox` as suggested by @meuh showed that Firefox is loading the config file:

```
open("/tmp/ff-build/bin/mozconfig.cfg", O_RDONLY) = 5
```

Putting a try/catch in `mozconfig.cfg` like this doesn't catch any problems, however:

```
// Disable default browser check
try {
    lockPref("browser.defaultbrowser.notificationbar", false);
    lockPref("browser.shell.checkDefaultBrowser", false);
    lockPref("browser.shell.skipDefaultBrowserCheck¨, true);

    // Disable updater
    lockPref("app.update.enabled¨, false);
} catch(e) {
    displayError("Error", e);
}
```

An empty `mozconfig.cfg` works, however, so a line-by-line removal and test was performed and it was discovered a strange double-quote character: `¨`. This is a syntax error, and rightfully the try/catch wasn't invoked.

Normally these kinds of errors would be caught in the developer panel, but that isn't available yet.

Running the script above through [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) reports

> Unclosed string.
>
> ```
> lockPref("app.update.enabled¨, false);
> ```

These are the steps I took to debug and solve that generic error message. I hope these steps help someone else too.